# publish odometry code

Tags: ros, arduino, navigation, odometry, publish

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi everyone

I have two arduino uno boards and i need to connect my encoders to each of them. I have two encoder and i dont want to use shield for them. I use rosserial stack to connect my laptop to arduino. Now i need a code to publish my odometry over ROS which consists of some transitions for use datas on gmapping package (like velocities). Does anyone know a good code?

Thanks too much :))

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/194910/publish-odometry-code/) by [mohammad](https://answers.ros.org/users/19955/mohammad/) on ROS Answers with karma: 75 on 2014-10-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You might want to take a look at the [differential_drive](http://wiki.ros.org/differential_drive) package.

I haven't used it myself, but it appears to take encoder readings and convert them to odometry and TF messages, and also provides a node to take standard Twist messages and convert them into individual motor commands.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-10-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1